# Why can't I add a bounty on my 48 hour old question?

Tags: support, bounties

I am trying to add a bounty on my 48+ hour old question on Stack Overflow, but I don't have an Add Bounty button anywhere (I checked the FAQ). The question meets the age limit, I have more than 50 reputation (on Stack Overflow specifically), so what could be preventing me adding the bounty?

If it helps, I don't seem to have an Add Bounty button on any questions...

Comment: You need at least 75 reputation to gain the privilege to set bounties; see [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di)

Comment: Yes, that helps - should it mention that on https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty which was where I looked to try to work out why I couldn't see the button?

Comment: Great idea - [just posted that request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363636/clearly-mention-the-75-reputation-requirement-to-start-a-bounty-in-the-help-cent).